# How to get the value from hash if the key is present using json mysql function json_extract

Tags: mysql, json, hash, mysql-function

data:

{"a": {"b": [{"name": "s", "value": "2"}, {"name": "r", "value": "100113"}, {"name": "r", "value": "1121202"}]}}

here is want to get the value when name is "r",

output:
value:
"100113"
"1121202"

what to do using json mysql functions like json_extract,json_search.

Comment: why using a dataformat that you can't handle

Comment: the data is fixed

Comment: @alpha can u help with this

Comment: Look for JSON_TABLE which is available since mysql 8